# Как сократить запись на JS - привести в нормальный вид (присвоение порядковых номеров)

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, способ привести код jquery в нормальный вид:

```
$('.go0').click(function(){
    carousel.trigger('owl.goTo', 0)
});

$('.go1').click(function(){
    carousel.trigger('owl.goTo', 1)
}); 

$('.go2').click(function(){
    carousel.trigger('owl.goTo', 2)
});

$('.go3').click(function(){
    carousel.trigger('owl.goTo', 3)
});

$('.go4').click(function(){
    carousel.trigger('owl.goTo', 4)
});

$('.go5').click(function(){
    carousel.trigger('owl.goTo', 5)
});

$('.go6').click(function(){
    carousel.trigger('owl.goTo', 6)
});

$('.go7').click(function(){
    carousel.trigger('owl.goTo', 7)
});

$('.go8').click(function(){
    carousel.trigger('owl.goTo', 8)
});
```

Элементов (`.go0`, `.go1` и т.д.) может быть бесконечно много, и писать их в таком виде не нормально.

К сожалению, не нашел как записать это в виде с n+1 или типа того.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение "не включая мозг":

```
for (var ix = 0; ix < 9; ix += 1) {
    $('.go' + ix).click(function (ix) {
        return function() {
            carousel.trigger('owl.goTo', ix);
        };
    }(ix));
}
```

Теперь нормальное решение:

Обычно у элементов переключения карусели общий предок и сами элементы идут в нем подряд. Поэтому достаточно найти номер потомка у предка, что в jQuery тривиальная задача. Предположим что у всех переключателей установлен класс `go`:

```
$('.go').click(function() {
    carousel.trigger('owl.goTo', $(this).index());
});
```

Если элементы `.go` находятся еще каждый в своей обертке, то вместо `$(this)` нужно будет указать предка, положение которого в пределах своего предка может дать номер слайда.

Comment: Спасибо! Вместо цифры 9 ( тут ix < 9;) - можно поставить любое число - и это будет максимальная цифра до которой будет работать скрипт?

Comment: да, это именно так

Comment: @den69 Обновил ответ

Comment: Благодарю! Всё работает как надо : )